# Cumulative Distribution of Squared Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

Suppose I have a random variable $Y$ who's probability density function is given by: $$f_{Y}(y)=a(y^2+y+1)$$

Where $a$ is some normalization constant. The function exists on the range $-3 \leq y \leq 3 $ and is zero everywhere else.

If I define another random variable $X = Y^2$, how would I determine the cumulative distribution function of $X$?

Comment: One way is to note $P(X < x) = P(Y^2 < x) = P(-\sqrt{x} < Y < \sqrt{x})$ which can be computed using the CDF of $Y$, or just integrating the pdf. My probability is rusty, so maybe there's a helpful theorem somewhere, but this is where I'd start.

Answer (score 2):

> If I define another random variable $X=Y^2$, how would I determine the cumulative distribution function of $X$?

Just evaluate it by integrating the pdf over the relevant domain.

$$\begin{align}F_{\small X}(x)~&=~\mathsf P(Y^2\leq x)\\[2ex]&=~\mathsf P(-\surd x\leq Y\leq \surd x)\\[2ex]&=~\int_{-\surd x}^{\surd x} f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$